# Webstorm: Can't enable "Node.js v0.x.x Core" in JS libraries, just pops up a window saying "Nothing to show"

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I am using the latest version of webstorm on Windows. I try going to Default Settings and I see my Node.js v0.10.31 Core under javascript libraries, I notice its not checked I try click it and it displays a window saying

```
    Choose modules for Node.js v0.10.31 Core
```

And says "Nothing to show", if I click OK then the check box next to the enable of the Node.js v0.10.31 Core  is unchecked.

Anyone else getting this issue ?

I can't seem to enable it at all.

Look forward to any insight anyone has.

P.s. I also tried it on my MAC too and the same thing happens, is it something I am doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are trying to enable libraries in default settings (File/Default settings), i.e. not for a real project, but for a project template.
Please open your project and then try enabling the library in WebStorm/Preferences/JavaScript/Libraries

Related Youtrack ticket: [WEB-13537](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13537)

Comment: that seemed to be it, in webstorm,preference,js,libraries i can enabled it. I am confused, what is the difference? is this because its a global setting.

Comment: still  a little confused.

Comment: enabling it in webstorm, pref,js, libraries means its enabled for all projects?

Comment: you can't enable a library for all projects at once. In /Preferences/JavaScript/Libraries you enable it for current project.